# Intersection of Records in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jooq, relational-division

Suppose I have labels with multiple stores associated with them like so:

```
label_id | store_id
--------------------
label_1  | store_1
label_1  | store_2
label_1  | store_3
label_2  | store_2
label_2  | store_3
label_3  | store_1
label_3  | store_2
```

Is there any good way in SQL (or jooq) to get all the store ids in the intersection of the labels? Meaning just return store_2 in the example above because store_2 is associated with label_1, label_2, and label_3? I would like a general method to handle the case where I have n labels.

Comment: "because store_2 is associated with label_1, label_2, and label_3".  I'm lost.  `store_1` has that association, not `store_2`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I was looking for the intersection of label_1_stores = [store_1, store_2, store_3], label_2_stores = [store_2, store_3] and label_3_stores = [store_1, store_2]. The intersection of those 3 arrays is only store_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then convert the query by @GMB into an SQL function that takes an array and returns a table of store_id's.

```
create or replace 
function stores_with_all_labels( label_list text[] )
 returns table (store_id text) 
 language  sql
as $$
    select store_id
      from label_store
     where label_id = any (label_list)
     group by store_id
    having count(*) = array_length(label_list,1);
$$;
```

Then all that's needed is a simple select.  See complete example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5521d889c37c4552029ca035be17c074).

Comment: Thats brilliant! It looks like that is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

This is a relational division problem, where you want the stores that have all possible labels. Here is an approach using aggregation:

```
select store_id
from mytable
group by store_id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct label_id) from mytable)
```

Note that this assumes no duplicate `(store_id, label_id)` tuples. Otherwise, you need to change the `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct label_id) = (select count(distinct label_id) from mytable)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What if I wanted provide an input of labels and find the intersection of all the stores associated with those labels? Is there a good way to modify the existing SQL you have now?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're also looking for a jOOQ solution, jOOQ supports [a synthetic relational division operator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/relational-division/), which produces a more academic approach to relational division, using relational algebra operators only:

```java
// Using jOOQ
T t1 = T.as("t1");
T t2 = T.as("t2");

ctx.select()
   .from(t1.divideBy(t2).on(t1.LABEL_ID.eq(t2.LABEL_ID)).returning(t1.STORE_ID).as("t"))
   .fetch();
```

This produces something like the following query:

```sql
select t.store_id
from (
  select distinct dividend.store_id
  from t dividend
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from t t2
    where not exists (
      select 1
      from t t1
      where dividend.store_id = t1.store_id
      and t1.label_id = t2.label_id 
    )
  )
) t
```

In plain English:

> Get me all the stores (dividend), for which there exists no label (t2) for which that store (dividend) has no entry (t1)

Or in other words

> If there was a label (t2) that a store (dividend) does not have (t1), then that store (dividend) would not have all the available labels.

This isn't necessarily more readable or faster than `GROUP BY` / `HAVING COUNT(*)` based implementations of relational divisions (as seen in other answers), in fact, the `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` based solutions are probably preferrable here, especially since only one table is involved. A future version of jOOQ might use the `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` approach, instead: [#10450](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10450)

But in jOOQ, it might be quite convenient to write this way, and you asked for a jOOQ solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are three particular labels you want, you can use:

```
select store_id
from t
where label in (1, 2, 3)
group by store_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

If you want *only* those three labels and nothing else, then:

```
select store_id
from t
group by store_id
having count(*) = 3 and
       count(*) filter (where label in (1, 2, 3)) = count(*);
```